# Xcode 4.5 debugging skips section of a function when stepping through code, even with breakpoints set (c++)

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging

So I have a function here that allegedly reads values from a .cfg file and the file is set up correctly, but my values are not being reflected by changes I make to the file. So I debug. The problem is that it skips over the iterations where the value is looked for! So I can't tell if it's just accepting the default value, or if something else is wrong.

```
bool ConfigReader::GetBool(const std::string theSection,
                           const std::string theName, const bool theDefault) const
{
    bool anResult = theDefault; // this is the line where I have a breakpoint set

    // Check if theSection really exists
    std::map<const std::string, typeNameValue*>::const_iterator iter;
    iter = mSections.find(theSection);
    if(iter != mSections.end())
    {
        // Try to obtain the name, value pair
        typeNameValue* anMap = iter->second;
        if(NULL != anMap)
        {
            typeNameValueIter iterNameValue;
            iterNameValue = anMap->find(theName);
            if(iterNameValue != anMap->end())
            {
                anResult = ParseBool(iterNameValue->second, theDefault);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the result found or theDefault assigned above
    return anResult; // this is the line where it skips to (not much help)
}
```

I've tried putting breakpoints on lines in between the skip, but it skips them anyway.

I'm not sure if my issue is related to this, but it sounds similar:
[Stepping through the code is stopping on STL code when debugging c++ with Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099916/stepping-through-the-code-is-stopping-on-stl-code-when-debugging-c-with-xcode)

Anybody know what could be happening here, or what I could do to fix/avoid it?
Also, if I posted incorrectly I apologize in advance.

Call to the GetBool function:

```
mProperties.Add<bool>("bMusicOn",
                      settingsConfig.GetAsset().GetBool("music", "on", true));
```

Comment: Obvious opening question that likely doesn't even need to be asked: is it definitely a debug build? Release builds don't always map 1:1 to source code lines in the order originally presented.

Comment: I should have thought of that. I switched over to release because of a linker error that would run a template instead of my code. I did the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372229/warning-wuninitialized-is-not-supported-without-o

and now it debugs properly. Thanks.